# Spotfire Webplayer Auto Refresh 6.5.2

Tags: tibco, spotfire

I am looking for the solution for Spotfire Webplayer Auto Refresh for version 6.5.2

I am aware of a similar question being asked in the forum, but the answer has not been able to resolve my query.

**What I have done:**
I have the information link connected to a Oracle table and this Information link is being reloaded periodically every 5 minutes.( The solution in the previous posts).
The users are logging into the webpayer, every time they want to see the latest values in the visualizations.So basically, they are closing the visualization and reopening it.

**What is the query:**
Users need not close and open the visualizations to see the latest values. The webplayer screen should automatically refresh in periodic intervals and show the latest values.It should be like a page reload in the browser in regular intervals.

Can anyone help me with this query?

Regards,
Kaka

Answer (score 0):

Spotfire provides possibility to add the JavaScript to the dashboard so perhaps adding JavaScript that would reload the page at particular interval would be your bet here ?

Please check the link https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/6.0.0-november-2013/userguide-webhelp/text/text_javascript_example_scripts.htm.

Comment: Hi Jacek..The solution which you provided is on the visualization level. I am looking help in terms of the browser refresh without having to do anything on the visualization or the text area in it. Can you suggest anything more on these lines?

Comment: I dont know of any option within Spotfire to set the page refresh. It is though a typical web development task. You need to take into account that it is a customization of a web player application that you need to do.